# Turning off third monitor turns off the second, doesn't do opposite

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors

So my display is being super weird, and has since I think my last install of win 10 which was a few months ago?

When I turn off display 2, both display 2 and 3 turn off and both are disabled moving everything to display 1. When I turn off display 3, display 2 and 1 are fine and nothing is moved from where it belongs. Display 2/3 are plugged into my igpu and display 1 is plugged into my gtx 560, both of which have their latest drivers installed. display 2 also does this when the monitor sleeps from windows' set timer. Latest drivers for both my GTX 560 and my i5 3570k's gpu are installed. I don't want display 3 to do anything when I turn it off, like how display 2 does nothing when I turn it off. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: If you change the main monitor is the behaviour the same? Is there a pattern you could see? Would you try all three configuration (changing the main display to 1,2 and then 3 and check every time what happens when you turn off display number 2 and 3. Would you please update your question with the connections used on which monitor (VGA, DVI, HDMI,...).

Comment: no matter which one is my main display it still turns off the same monitor. monitor 3 is on dvi, 2 is on vga and 1 is on hdmi

Comment: are you able to change the connection? just to see if it is the type of connection and/or the monitor. I assume it is the type of connection. Are you able to use two outputs on your gtx? what happens if you change the primary graphic adapter to be used in BIOS?

Comment: i looked in my bios, allocated my igpu some more ram and turned off a sleep thingo, did nothing. I might give my GTX 560 my third monitor, see how things go. I can change the connection but it'll require me moving the monitors so i'd rather now.

Comment: So no primary graphic adapter setting in BIOS? And I meant just to replug the monitors on your computer, don't think you have to move them for that!? Let us know if changing from igp to gtx will  change something.

Comment: yeah some of the cables are too short so i can't change them. i didn't wanna mess with the dedicated gpu in my bios since i was gonna play CS:GO but i'm about to change from the igpu to the 560 now. edit: works great, thanks. can't believe i didn't consider that.

Comment: I assume it is, as now most often the igpu has support for up to 3 monitors, that the system decided to switch off your 3rd monitor which was connected to the gtx. As you now are using two on the gtx it does not trigger a display change which would disconnect an additional screen. This is just an assumption from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional information from the OP, it seems that the problem was that he had two monitors connected to the internal graphic card and one to the additional GTX. As he changed the connection to have two monitors connected to the additional GTX and only one to the internal graphic card - the problem disappeared. My assumption is (an only an assumption) that as now most often the internal gpu have support for up to 3 monitors, that the system decided to switch off the 3rd monitor which was connected to the gtx. As now two monitors are connected to the gtx it does not trigger a display change which seems to disconnect an additional screen.

Comment: my setup worked fine on my previous windows install, so i don't think it's this, but thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad you fixed your issue.